# How would I link to thumbnails in a subdirectory, when using php to get a list of images?

Tags: php, thumbnails, subdirectory

I'm sorry if the title is a little vague ... I'm still relatively new at PHP (3 months or so) Also, my native tongue is not English, so please bear with me :) I have also searched this site and google extensively to try and find a solution, but without any luck.

I have a script set up in my images directory that scans all the subdirectories, and then outputs a list of links that, if clicked, will take you to a page, where all the images of the selected subdirectory are displayed. The path to such a page would be:

```
www.mysite.com/images/list_images.php?folderName=RandomFolder
```

The code for this:

```
images/index.php

<?php
  $path = 'images/' ;
  $results = scandir($path);
  for ($i=0;$i<count($results);$i++)
  {
    $result=$results[$i];
    if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') 
      continue;
    if (is_dir($path . '/' . $result)) 
     {
      echo "<a href='list_images.php?folderName=$result'>$result</a><br/>";
     }
   }
?>

--------------------
list_images.php

<?php
   if(isset($_GET['folderName'])) 
      $folder=$_GET['folderName'];
   $path = 'images/'.$folder.'/' ;
   $images = glob($path . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
   foreach ($images as $image)
    {
     echo "<a href='$image'><img src='$image'/></a>";
    }
?>
```

Now, my question:
In each of my image subdirectories I have another subdirectory called 'thumbs', that contains - yes, you guessed it - thumbnails. Each thumbnail is named exactly the same as its corresponding file in the directory above it. Now, how would I make the img src in the above code to point to the thumb?

Any help would be very welcome! Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I looked over my code again, and I made few extra lines. It still doesn't work, but at least it now outputs thumbnails, which links to the larger image. Here's the new code:

```
list_images.php
    if (isset($_GET['folderName'])) $folder=$_GET['folderName'];
    $path = 'images/'.$folder.'/' ;
    $thumb_path = ''.$path.'/thumbs/';
    $thumbs = glob($thumb_path . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    $images = glob($path . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach ($thumbs as $thumb){
        foreach ($images as $image){
            echo "<a class='fancybox' href='$image'><img src='$thumb'/></a>";
        }
    }
```

It *kinda* works now. The only problem is, that it outputs 13 identical thumbnails to each picture - and it does it 13 times (for a directory containing 13 image files) so there is 169 thumbnails in total.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the folder name is `thumbs`, there is no reason you can't hardcode this.  Take a look at the following.

```
echo "<a href='$image'><img src='thumbs/$image'/></a>";
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I've already tried what you suggests. It works, but the thumbnail images somehow doesnt work - they are shown as little "broken" images ... (I'm not sure what they are called)

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `str_replace` on the path.

If the path to the image is `mydir\image01\pic01.jpg`

```
str_replace('image01','image01\thumb',$image);
```

would point to `mydir\image01\thumb\pic01.jpg`

Comment: But then wouldn't I have to make a str_replace for each and every single imagefolder?

Comment: Ah, I now see you have `$path = 'images/'.$folder.'/'`. Why not just put `thumbs/` behind it, so it scans the thumbs-folder?

Comment: No that wouldn't work either - I have tried it earlier. This will also transform the links to point to the thumbs - not the larger files.

Comment: That last part is solved by using @Sajans solution. And have you checked the paths to the images in the generated html? It sounds like there is some error in referencing the thumbnails.

Comment: Due to the way the code is set up, the path to thumbs (using this method) would be `images/random_folder/images/random_folder/thumbs`

Comment: Only itterate over the thumbs _or_ the images. Remove the `foreach($images)` or the `foreach($thumbs)`